# Swift 4/Google Maps Custom Info Window Marker - can't get the "didTapAt"

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have searched the interwebs high and low.  I see tons of examples of this same code and the code here is mostly "copy/paste".  Yet I can't get it to work.

My ultimate goal is to have interactive elements (UIButton) in the info window of a marker.  This marker happens to be the "user marker" or a marker at the spot of the user's location.  After some debugging, I can see that some of the code simply never executes, but it is unclear why.  I have added comments below to call out the code

[My repo is here, feel free to poke at it](https://github.com/bbookman/BMap/tree/DidTapAt)

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
var customInfoWindow:CustomInfoWindow?
var marker = GMSMarker()
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let zoom:Float = 15

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ALL THIS WORKS FINE

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    self.customInfoWindow = CustomInfoWindow().loadView()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
        return
    }
   // ALL THIS WORKS FINE

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.first else {
        return
    }
   // ALL THIS WORKS FINE

    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: self.zoom, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    marker.isTappable = true
    //marker.title = "Hi"
    marker.map = self.mapView
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    self.marker = marker

    // NONE OF THIS CODE APPEARS TO EXECUTE

    //get position of tapped marker
    let position = marker.position
    mapView.animate(toLocation: position)
    let point = mapView.projection.point(for: position)
    let newPoint = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: point)
    let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(newPoint)
    mapView.animate(with: camera)

    let opaqueWhite = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.85)
    customInfoWindow?.layer.backgroundColor = opaqueWhite.cgColor
    customInfoWindow?.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    customInfoWindow?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: position)
    customInfoWindow?.center.y -= 100
    customInfoWindow?.customWindowLabel.text = "This is my Custom Info Window"
    customInfoWindow?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.mapView.addSubview(customInfoWindow!)

    return false
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
   // NONE OF THIS CODE APPEARS TO EXECUTE
    return UIView()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
 // NONE OF THIS CODE APPEARS TO EXECUTE
    customInfoWindow?.removeFromSuperview()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
// NONE OF THIS CODE APPEARS TO EXECUTE - and i don't expect it to unless there is a position change, but wanted to make a note

    let position = self.marker.position
    customInfoWindow?.center = mapView.projection.point(for: position)
    customInfoWindow?.center.y -= 100
}
```

}

P.S. If you happen to know of a plug and play pod or some other super easy reusable package LMK (Latest Swift version or latest Obj-C would be best)

Comment: outdate link for the repo

Answer (score 0):

You can add the delegate to listen to callbacks

```
 self.mapView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

The key was to add two lines to the ViewController.  First I forgot to instantiate an instance of the custom window view, and then as pointed out above, I forgot to add a delegate for callbacks

```
self.customInfoWindow = CustomInfoWindow().loadView()
self.mapView.delegate = self
```